# Uploading ZIP via Google App Engine servlet, and saving content to Cloud Storage (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, zip, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I'm searching for the best approach to do the following:

1. User uploads a large (~500 Megabytes) ZIP file via an App-Engine servlet
2. All the extracted content should be saved to a Cloud Storage bucket
3. A DB record should be inserted to a table on CloudSQL with the URL of every stored file.

What will be the best approach to implement such a behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: The best approach is to do exactly as you said it - it's not clear what problem(s) are you facing when implementing it.

Comment: What I said is only the required results. I don't know how to handle a 500 Megabytes file on app engine application without loading it into memory and reading the content with ZipFile in Java.

I believe there should be a better way to "stream" the content directly to cloud storage.

Comment: why not uploaded it directly to cloud storage?

Comment: You simply can't upload a single 500 MB file via App-Engine servlet, since no HTTP request may exceed the size of 32MB (see: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Requests -> Incoming Bandwidth).

Comment: You should be able to upload with https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Uploading_a_blob which allows to upload into cloud storage as well.

Comment: Thanks @konqi, this should do the job! +1

Answer (score 1):

You can easily upload the 500 MB .ZIP directly to GCS, but then you can't *unpack* it there -- and it's too large to get it into app engine for unpacking. Rather, for this latter task, I would use google *compute* engine, which is not subject to the same limitations as google *app* engine.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. However: 1) How to I let my users upload DIRECTLY from the web app to Cloud Storage?
2) How will me server side (app engine or compute engine) get an indication that a new file was uploaded?

Comment: to let users upload directly to GCS, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26083985/upload-files-to-google-cloud-storage-with-google-app-engine-python .  For watching changes on a GCS bucket from GAE, see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Application_Example .