# How to upload video through Python GAE to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a python GAE application I'm developing locally. I'd like to add the feature that users can upload image or video from computer to Google Cloud Storage.

I've looked over the Google Cloud Storage documentation a few times. Perhaps I'm not smart enough to grasp the workings quickly.

I would really appreciate it if someone can run down a very simple example of the entire process, from user uploading file through a POST form, to storing it in the Google Cloud Storage, and also how to store the path to file in the NDB datastore, and finally how to retrieve file and render it to user.

Thanks a lot

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26083985/upload-files-to-google-cloud-storage-with-google-app-engine-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example [here](https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcs-upload) showing a direct upload to GCS using a form POST and a signed url. After the upload GCS uses a callback to send you the GCS object path.

[image]

A policy document defines what a user (with our without a Google account) can upload with a form POST.